# Analyzing cluster homogeneity and using Cluster Distance Performance Operator in RapidMiner

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, rapidminer

I have implemented k-means clustering on a dataset. I have tried analyzing k of clustering by looking at parallel and deviation chart given in rapid-miner.

The aim is to analyse homogeneity of clusters.Out of various performance models given, the operator "**Cluster Distance Performance**" operator is used on results of k-means clustering.

1. Are there any other operators that can provide such analysis?
2. The dataset that I have has numeric vectors with large values (in
   hundreds and thousands), also I have a dataset which have extremely
   small values (upto 5th-8th place of decimal).

I am not sure of how to interpret the results that I get from the operator  "Cluster Distance Performance" as shown below

Centroid Table result

[image]

and Performance Vector operator result is

[image]
Can someone please help me with this? Though I read that smaller the value of Davies Bouldin better is the clustering.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find the "best" clusterings then you have to vary k and calculate different cluster validity measures to compare how these vary as k varies. Davies-Bouldin is often a nice one because the "best" is signalled by a minimum. The definition of best is from the point of view of the mathematical technique used to construct the validity measure (which is based on sound and logical techniques) but a person always has to look at the clustering to decide if the result actually means something.

Comment: If you want some guidance about writing a process to iterate over all possible values of k and calculating a validity measure, you can see an example here http://rapidminernotes.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/counting-clusters-part-ii.html

Answer (score 0):

You should look into other performance metrics, since by applying only one can prevent you from seeing the big picture.
Adding to what's mentioned by Andrew:

- Calinski-Harabasz score
- Silhouette score
- Elbow method